# A complex sql statement

Tags: sql

I need some assistance with an sql statement. I have a database which has a tests table and a clients table, the clientId being a foreign key in the test table. How can I retrieve how many people with the name XYZ has failed more than X tests? 
I have tried a couple different things so far and believe this to be along the right lines..

```
SELECT C.name, T.ondate, T.status 
FROM client C, test T 
WHERE C.name='xyz' AND T.status='Fail'
```

Comment: How to you join the table.  And don't used the old style of ,

Comment: @Paparazzi I joined the table using  FOREIGN KEY (clientNo) REFERENCES client (clientNo)
 ON UPDATE CASCADE
 ON DELETE CASCADE,

Comment: Sounds like homework. Here are 2 links to get you started: [How to Count](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx), [How to Joins](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191472(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT C.name, count(*) 
  FROM client C 
  JOIN test T
         on T.clientId = C.clientId 
        and T.status= 'Fail'
 group by C.name 
having count(*) > 2
```

Comment: Thanks, you refreshed my memory on joins!